# Django does not create foreign key in sqlite table

Tags: django, django-models

I use sqlite in a Django project. I created a model called Employee, and then Education, but I forgot to add a foreign key to Employee.

When I found the problem, I added the foreign key:

```
class Education(models.Model):
    employee=models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE),
```

But when run manage.py makemigrations, it says nothing changed.

So I tried to delete the sqlite database file, delete all migrations and tried to create a new database. It still say nothing changed! the sqlite database file is created, with 0 size!

What is happening to django?

Comment: Remove the comma at the end of the ForeignKey line, you are defining a tuple instead of just a model field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Iain Shelvington pointed out, this is a mistake in code that line has extra comma. This is a frequent mistake for programmers of other languages when writing python :(